# Mongoose save() does not work on all models

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I am using Nodejs, Express and Mongoose to store data. I have 2 Models: Contact and Shop. My contact schema works, it sends data to my db. But Shop simply won't and I am pulling out my hair, not understanding why. Currently I am trying to hard code the data to just get it saved to the db. The database is connected, because the Contact model sends data with no problem.

In MongoDB I have a collection called "shops" and I want to insert the data in there.

My Shop Model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const ShopSchema = new Schema({
    shopName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    shopImage: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    shopDescription: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    shopCategory: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
}, { timestamps:true });

const Shop = mongoose.model('Shop', ShopSchema);
module.exports = Shop;
```

My shop router:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const Shop = require('../models/shopModel.js');

router.get('/add-shop', (req, res) => {
    ShopCategory.find()
        .then(result => res.render('shop/add-shop', { title: "Add a Shop" }))
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
});

router.post(('/add-shop', (req, res) => {
    const shop = new Shop({
        shopName: "A shop name",
        shopImage: '88.jpg',
        shopDescription: 'This is a description',
        shopCategory: "Food"
    });
    shop.save()
        .then(result => console.log(result))
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
}));

module.exports = router;
```

My app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const app = express();

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
const db = 'mongodb+srv://user:pass@nodetuts-6iczn.mongodb.net/shop?retryWrites=true&w=majority';

mongoose.connect(db, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
    .then(result => app.listen(3000))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));

const shopRoutes = require('./routes/shop.js');
app.use(shopRoutes);
```

I don't know what I am missing. I compared everything to my Contact model that works, and there is also no error. I checked that I am connected to the database and I am.

Comment: Does your catch section after `save()` log any error ?

Comment: You can try `Model.create()` instead of `Model.save()`.

The docs are https://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html#constructing-documents

Comment: No error. But I have a new suspicion that it is due to my directory structure and I am not getting the route to post. When I am on /add-shop page and I refresh it then I get a 404 error even though the URL endpoint stays the same being /add-shop. I will create a new question to include my directory structure. I don't think it is a database issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have define `'/add-shop'` routes for your `POST` request simple way to fix this error is to remove `()` brackets that you have defined before your `'/add-shop'` routes so, code will look like this.

```
router.post('/add-shop', (req, res) => {
    const shop = new Shop({
        shopName: "A shop name",
        shopImage: '88.jpg',
        shopDescription: 'This is a description',
        shopCategory: "Food"
    });
    shop.save()
        .then(result => console.log(result))
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
});
```

Hope this helps!!